# React (with Ant Design table) is **really** slow: how to optimize?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I created a mini-scheduling system in react using Ant Design table components. My issue is that when we add around 60 lines (not that crazy right?), the system is **really** slow (even scrolling horizontally produces a small lag). Like any operation I do takes maybe 5 seconds:

[image]

Any idea what I’m doing wrong, and how we can debug these issues?

**EDIT** I also tried to ad `memo` and `useCallback`, but same issue…

**Example code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Planning</title>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-redux@8.0.5/dist/react-redux.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@reduxjs/toolkit@1.9.3/dist/redux-toolkit.umd.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1.11.7/dayjs.min.js "></script>
    <script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/antd@5.5.0/dist/antd.js "></script>
    <link href=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/antd@5.5.0/dist/reset.min.css " rel="stylesheet">

    
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="planning"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
      const { useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState, memo, useCallback } = React;
      const { useDispatch, useSelector, Provider } = ReactRedux;
      const { configureStore, createSlice } = RTK;      
      const { Button, Form, Input, InputNumber, Popconfirm, Table, Select, Tag, Slider } = antd;

      
      // ***************************
      // Store
      // ***************************

      const stateToSaveReducer = createSlice({
        name: "stateToSave",
        initialState: {
          // We try to keep everything in a single table, to provide simple copy/paste and visualisation etc...
          allSchedules: [
            {
              columns: [
                // subsetOf are list separated with ;, this allows easy import/export to csv/excel/…
                {field: "Place", kind: "subsetOf", description: "Endroit(s) où la personne travaille.", values: ["Place 1", "Place 2"]},
                {field: "Type", kind: "oneOf", description: "Type de travail, soit aides soignantes, soit agents service logistique", values: ["AS", "ASL"]},
                {field: "Pourcentage", kind: "intBetween", values: [0, 100], description: "Pourcentage travail.", marks: [0, 50, 80, 100]},
              ],
              allowedTags: [
                {name: "Place 1"},
                {name: "Place 2"},
                {name: "Morning"},
                {name: "Lunch"},
                {name: "Meeting 1"},
                {name: "Meeting 2"},
                {name: "Evening"},
              ],
              nbDays: 3*7,
              scheduleAndEmployee: [
                {
                  name: "Alice Montest",
                  Place: "Place 1;Place 2",
                  Type: "AS",
                  Pourcentage: "80",
                  days: [
                    // Just a list of tags, it will be turned later into time etc.
                    // for now these tags have no meaning.
                    "Lunch;Meeting 1;Morning;Place1",
                    "Evening",
                  ], 
                },
                {
                  name: "Bob Monnomdefam",
                  Place: "MAPPA",
                  Type: "AS",
                  Pourcentage: "100",
                  days: [
                    // Just a list of tags, it will be turned later into time etc.
                    // for now these tags have no meaning.
                    "Meeting 2;Morning;Place 1",
                    "Evening",
                    "Lunch"
                  ], 
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        reducers:{
          removeEmployee: (state, action) => {
            state.allSchedules[action.payload.idSchedule].scheduleAndEmployee = state.allSchedules[action.payload.idSchedule].scheduleAndEmployee.filter((e,i) => i != action.payload.key)
          },
          addEmployee: (state, action) => {
            var t = state.allSchedules[action.payload.idSchedule].scheduleAndEmployee;
            t.push({
              name: "Employé " + (t.length+1)
            });
          },
          // Duplicate the last employee, except for name, of course, and days
          duplicateLastEmployee: (state, action) => {
            var t = state.allSchedules[action.payload.idSchedule].scheduleAndEmployee;
            const {name, days, ...rest} = t[t.length-1];
            t.push({...rest,
                    name: "Employé " + (t.length+1)
            });
          },
          updateEmployee: (state, action) => {
            var t = state.allSchedules[action.payload.idSchedule].scheduleAndEmployee;
            const {key, ...rest} = action.payload.newEmployee;
            state.allSchedules[action.payload.idSchedule].scheduleAndEmployee[key] = rest;
          },
          updateEmployeeDay: (state, action) => {
            var t = state.allSchedules[action.payload.idSchedule].scheduleAndEmployee;
            if (!state.allSchedules[action.payload.idSchedule].scheduleAndEmployee[action.payload.key].hasOwnProperty("days")) {
              state.allSchedules[action.payload.idSchedule].scheduleAndEmployee[action.payload.key].days = [];
            }
            state.allSchedules[action.payload.idSchedule].scheduleAndEmployee[action.payload.key].days[action.payload.day] = action.payload.dayContent;
          }

        }
      })


      const store = configureStore({
        reducer: {
          stateToSave: stateToSaveReducer.reducer
        },
      })

      const { removeEmployee, addEmployee, duplicateLastEmployee, updateEmployee, updateEmployeeDay } = stateToSaveReducer.actions

      const selectorScheduleAndEmployee = (idSchedule, state) => {
        return state.stateToSave.allSchedules[idSchedule].scheduleAndEmployee.map((x, i) => {return {...x, key:i}})
      }



      // ***************************
      // Main grid
      // ***************************
      
      const AddEmployeeButton = ({...props}) => {
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const [nbEmployee, setNbEmployee] = useState(3);
        const handleAdd = useCallback((e) => {
          Array(nbEmployee).fill().map(() => dispatch(duplicateLastEmployee({idSchedule: props.idSchedule})))
        },[nbEmployee, props.idSchedule]);
        const handleClick = useCallback(e => {e.stopPropagation();e.preventDefault()}, []);
        return <Button onClick={handleAdd} type="primary" style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
          Ajouter <InputNumber min={1} value={nbEmployee} onChange={setNbEmployee} onClick={handleClick} size="small" /> employé(e)
        </Button>
      };

      const ComponentIntBetween = memo(({oldRow, nameField, values, marks, idSchedule, ...props}) => {
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const valueSelect = useSelector((state) =>
          parseInt(state.stateToSave.allSchedules[idSchedule].scheduleAndEmployee[oldRow.key][nameField]));
        const handleChange = (newValue) => {
          const newEmployee = {...oldRow, [nameField]: newValue.toString()};
          dispatch(updateEmployee({idSchedule: idSchedule, newEmployee: newEmployee}));
        };
        return <Slider
                 min={values[0]}
                 max={values[1]}
                 marks={Object.fromEntries(marks.map((x) => {return [x, x]}))}
                 style={{ width: "80%" }}
                 onChange={handleChange}
                 value={typeof valueSelect === 'number' ? valueSelect : 0}
        />
      });


      const ComponentSelectFromList = memo(({oldRow, nameField, values, idSchedule, ...props}) => {
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const valueSelect = useSelector((state) => state.stateToSave.allSchedules[idSchedule].scheduleAndEmployee[oldRow.key][nameField]);
        const handleChange = (newValue) => {
          const newEmployee = {...oldRow, [nameField]: newValue};
          dispatch(updateEmployee({idSchedule: idSchedule, newEmployee: newEmployee}));
        };
        return <Select
                 defaultValue={values[0]}
                 value={valueSelect}
                 style={{ width: "100%" }}
                 bordered={false}
                 onChange={handleChange}
                 options={values.map((x) => {return {value: x, label: x}})}
        />
      });

      const tagRender = memo((props) => {
        const { label, value, closable, onClose } = props;
        const onPreventMouseDown = useCallback((event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        },[]);
        return (
          <Tag
            onMouseDown={onPreventMouseDown}
            closable={closable}
            onClose={onClose}
            style={{
                marginRight: 3,
              }}
          >
            {label}
          </Tag>
        );
      });



      const ComponentSelectSubsetFromList = memo(({oldRow, nameField, values, idSchedule, ...props}) => {
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const valueSelect = useSelector((state) => state.stateToSave.allSchedules[idSchedule].scheduleAndEmployee[oldRow.key][nameField].split(";").filter(element => element));
        const handleChange = (newValue) => {
          const newEmployee = {...oldRow, [nameField]: newValue.join(";")};
          dispatch(updateEmployee({idSchedule: idSchedule, newEmployee: newEmployee}));
        };
        return <Select
                 mode="multiple"
                 showArrow
                 tagRender={tagRender}
                 value={valueSelect}
                 style={{ width: "100%" }}
                 bordered={false}
                 onChange={handleChange}
                 options={values.map((x) => {return {value: x}})}
        />
      });

      const ComponentDay = memo(({oldRow, day, idSchedule, ...props}) => {
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const valueSelect = useSelector((state) => {
          if (!state.stateToSave.allSchedules[idSchedule].scheduleAndEmployee[oldRow.key].hasOwnProperty("days")) {
            return []
          }
          if (state.stateToSave.allSchedules[idSchedule].scheduleAndEmployee[oldRow.key].days.hasOwnProperty(day)) {
            return state.stateToSave.allSchedules[idSchedule].scheduleAndEmployee[oldRow.key].days[day].split(";").filter(element => element)
          } else {
            return []
        }});
        const allowedTags = useSelector((state) =>
          state.stateToSave.allSchedules[idSchedule].allowedTags);
        const handleChange = (newValue) => {
          dispatch(updateEmployeeDay({idSchedule: idSchedule, key: oldRow.key, day: day, dayContent: newValue.join(";")}));
        };
        return <Select
                 mode="multiple"
                 showArrow
                 tagRender={tagRender}
                 value={valueSelect}
                 style={{ width: "100%" }}
                 bordered={false}
                 onChange={handleChange}
                 options={allowedTags.map((x) => {return {value: x.name}})}
        />
      });

      const EditableContext = React.createContext(null);
      const EditableRow = memo(({ index, ...props }) => {
        const [form] = Form.useForm();
        return (
          <Form form={form} component={false}>
            <EditableContext.Provider value={form}>
              <tr {...props} />
            </EditableContext.Provider>
          </Form>
        );
      });

      const EditableCell = memo(({
        title,
        editable,
        children,
        dataIndex,
        record,
        handleSave,
        ...restProps
      }) => {
        const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
        const inputRef = useRef(null);
        const form = useContext(EditableContext);
        useEffect(() => {
          if (editing) {
            inputRef.current.focus();
          }
        }, [editing]);
        const toggleEdit = useCallback(() => {
          setEditing(!editing);
          form.setFieldsValue({
            [dataIndex]: record[dataIndex],
          });
        },[editing,dataIndex,record]);
        const save = async () => {
          try {
            const values = await form.validateFields();
            toggleEdit();
            handleSave({
              ...record,
              ...values,
            });
          } catch (errInfo) {
            console.log('Save failed:', errInfo);
          }
        };
        let childNode = children;
        if (editable) {
          childNode = editing ? (
            <Form.Item
              style={{
                  margin: 0,
                }}
              name={dataIndex}
              rules={[
                  {
                    required: true,
                    message: `${title} is required.`,
                  },
                ]}
            >
              <Input ref={inputRef} onPressEnter={save} onBlur={save} />
            </Form.Item>
          ) : (
            <div
              className="editable-cell-value-wrap"
              style={{
                  paddingRight: 24,
                }}
              onClick={toggleEdit}
            >
              {children}
            </div>
          );
        }
        return <td {...restProps}>{childNode}</td>;
      });


      // Main table
      const Antgrid = () => {
        const idSchedule = 0;
        const dataSource = useSelector((state) => selectorScheduleAndEmployee(idSchedule, state));
        const customColumns = useSelector((state) => state.stateToSave.allSchedules[idSchedule].columns);
        const nbDays = useSelector((state) => state.stateToSave.allSchedules[idSchedule].nbDays);
        const dispatch = useDispatch()
        const defaultColumns = [
          {
            title: 'Nom',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            fixed: 'left',
            width: 180,
            editable: true
        }].concat(customColumns.map((c) => {
          // We add the columns like percent of work etc…
          // Depending on the type of the column, we display different components
          var col = {
            title: c.field,
            dataIndex: c.field,
            width: 180,
          };
          switch (c.kind) {
            case "oneOf":
              return {...col,
                      render: (_, record) => {
                        return <ComponentSelectFromList nameField={c.field} idSchedule={idSchedule} oldRow={record} values={c.values} />
                      }
              }
              break;
            case "subsetOf":
              return {...col,
                      render: (_, record) => {
                        return <ComponentSelectSubsetFromList nameField={c.field} idSchedule={idSchedule} oldRow={record} values={c.values} />
                      }
              }
              break;
            case "intBetween":
              return {...col,
                      render: (_, record) => {
                        return <ComponentIntBetween nameField={c.field} idSchedule={idSchedule} oldRow={record} values={c.values} marks={c.marks ? c.marks : []}/>
                      }
              }
              break;
            default:
              return col
          }
        })).concat(Array.from({length: nbDays}, (x,i) => {
          // We add the actual working days columns
          return {
            title: 'Day',
            dataIndex: ['days', i],
            width: 150,
            render: (_, record) => {
              return <ComponentDay day={i} idSchedule={idSchedule} oldRow={record} />
            }
          }
        })).concat([{
          title: 'Operations',
          dataIndex: 'Operations',
          width: 100,
          render: (_, record) => (
            dataSource.length >= 1 ? (
              <Popconfirm title="Sure to delete?" onConfirm={() => dispatch(removeEmployee({idSchedule: idSchedule, key: record.key}))}>
                <a>Delete</a>
              </Popconfirm>
            ) : null),
        }]);
        const handleSave = (row) => {
          dispatch(updateEmployee({idSchedule: idSchedule, newEmployee: row}))
        };
        // We override defaults table elements to make them editable
        const components = {
          body: {
            row: EditableRow,
            cell: EditableCell,
          },
        };
        
        const columns = defaultColumns.map((col) => {
          if (!col.editable) {
            return col;
          }
          return {
            ...col,
            onCell: (record) => ({
              record,
              editable: col.editable,
              dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
              title: col.title,
              handleSave,
            }),
          };
        });
        // const columns = defaultColumns;
        return (
          <div>
            <Table
              size="small"
              dataSource={dataSource}
              columns={columns}
              sticky
              pagination={false}
              scroll={{ x: "100%" }}
              components={components}
            />
            <AddEmployeeButton idSchedule={idSchedule}/>
          </div>
        );
      };

      function App() {
        return (<>
          <h1>Planning</h1>
          <Antgrid/>
        </>)
      };

      const container = document.getElementById('planning');
      const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
      root.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
          <Provider store={store}>            
            <App />
          </Provider>
        </React.StrictMode>
      )
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution to the refresh problem (but not to the long creation time… but that time is only once so I can live with it for now). The idea is to combine:

1. `memo()` on all cells
2. `useCallback` on all functions that are callbacks
3. `useMemo()` on all styles and objects that might change
4. and **very importantly** (this only change might even be enough?): set `shouldCellUpdate` like in:

```
render: (_, record) => {
  return <EditableCell nameField={"name"} idSchedule={idSchedule} oldRow={record} />
},
// https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/23763
shouldCellUpdate: (record, prevRecord) => !shallowEqual(record, prevRecord)
```

there is still a bit of lag, but it’s maybe half a second so I can live with that. I also changed the first editable text zone into another cell zone, this way I don’t need to worry if `shouldCellUpdate` exists for this custom row.